# Can a database connection be reused?

Tags: c++, sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a program where I can access a PostgreSQL database.  The problem is I keep getting a

> WARNING: There is already a transaction in progress

message and the program exits soon after.  Do I need to close and reopen the connection when I need it or can I fix the issue and reuse the same connection throughout my program?

```
    int i = 0;
    std::string spassw = "";
    std::string suname = "";

    theconn = NULL;

    // Make a connection to the database
    theconn = PQconnectdb("user=postgres password=changeme dbname=database hostaddr=127.0.0.1    port=5432");

    // Check to see that the backend connection was successfully made
    if ( PQstatus(theconn) != CONNECTION_OK )   {

        std::cout << "Connection to database failed.\nPress any key to continue.\n";
        PQfinish(theconn);
        getchar();
        exit(1);
     }

    PGresult *res  = PQexec(theconn, "BEGIN");

    if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK)    {

        printf("BEGIN command failed");
        PQclear(res);
        PQfinish(theconn);
        std::cout << "Goodbye.\n";
        getchar();
        exit(1);
    }

    // Clear result
    PQclear(res);

    res = PQexec(theconn, "DECLARE emprec CURSOR FOR select * from dbtable");

    if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK)    {

        printf("DECLARE CURSOR failed\n");
        PQclear(res);
        PQfinish(theconn);
        std::cout << "Goodbye.\n";
        getchar();
        exit(1);
     }

    PQclear(res);
    res = PQexec(theconn, "FETCH ALL in emprec");

    if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_TUPLES_OK) {

        printf("FETCH ALL failed");
        PQclear(res);
        PQfinish(theconn);
        std::cout << "Goodbye.\n";
        getchar();
        exit(1);
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < PQntuples(res); i++ )    {

        std::string suname = PQgetvalue( res, i, 0 );
        std::string spassw = PQgetvalue( res, i, 1 );

        if( pname == suname && pword == spassw )    {

        res = PQexec( theconn, "COMMIT");
        PQclear(res);

        res = PQexec(theconn, "CLOSE emprec" );
        PQclear(res);

        // End the transaction
        res = PQexec(theconn, "END");

        // Clear result
        PQclear(res);
        return true;
        }

    }

    res = PQexec( theconn, "COMMIT");
        PQclear(res);

    res = PQexec(theconn, "CLOSE emprec");
    PQclear(res);

    // End the transaction
    res = PQexec(theconn, "END");

    // Clear result
    PQclear(res);


    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the code has  a `BEGIN` that starts a transaction, it should have one (and only one) matching `COMMIT`, or `END`, but not both.

The reason is that `END` is in fact a synonym for `COMMIT`. Here's what the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-end.html) says about it:

> This command is a PostgreSQL extension that is equivalent to COMMIT.

Given how your code is currently organized with the closing of the cursor, the occurrences of:

```
   res = PQexec( theconn, "COMMIT");
        PQclear(res);
```

should just be removed.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a tip: you can use a single connection throughout the entire execution of your application, but you need to pay attention to transactions. The warning you're receiving is due to a transaction in progress, so make sure you're committing and closing the transaction properly. I'm not able to give you an advice about your c++ code, since I'm not a c++ programmer, but it looks like your problem is not language-specific, but conceptual. My apologizes if otherwise.